# UITableViewCell blink on LongPress

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got an `UITableView`and to its `UITableViewCell`s I'm adding a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`like this:

```
// Setup Event-Handling
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTableViewCellLongPress:)];

[cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

[longPress setDelegate:self];
```

I would like the cell to blink when the event is fired and I also would like to forbid the standard behaviour (that it turns blue when pressed once).

How can I do this in my `handleTableViewCellLongPress`-Method?

Thanks!

Comment: well if you can detect which cell is long touched, u can just put a uiimage with uianimation of alpha or visible. and for blue selection you can do cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

Answer (score 4):

You could use chaining animations:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = ...
  // remove blue selection
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 

  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]    
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTableViewCellLongPress:)] autorelease];
  [cell addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

  return cell;
}

- (void) handleTableViewCellLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
  if (gesture.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    return;

  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gesture.view;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    // hide
    cell.alpha = 0.0;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // show after hiding
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
      cell.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
  }];
}
```